# LINQ with dynamic objects

Tags: c#, linq

Try to sort through a bunch of examples, and can't seem to make this work ... which leads me to believe I might be trying the impossible! :)

I have the following code in my view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Map</legend>
    <table class="map">
        @for (var y = 0; y <= (int)ViewBag.Map.Height; y++)
        {
            <tr>
                @for (var x = 0; x <= (int)ViewBag.Map.Width; x++)
                {
                    <td>@ViewBag.Map.MapTiles.Where(z => z.X == x && z.Y == y)</td>
                }
            </tr>                
        }
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

Map is a `dynamic` object.

When I run this,  I get the following error:

Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Is there a way to get around this and keep my LINQ query simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast first, as the compiler says

```
   <td>@((IEnumerable<MapTileOrWhat>)(ViewBag.Map.MapTiles)).Where(z => z.X == x && z.Y == y)</td>
```

Comment: MapTileOrWhat is a dynamic ... that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It should not matter. Linq works on enumerables. The where clause is applied to your dynamics and for some reason this does not work.